# NSPrintOperation Never Calls drawRect:

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, printing

I have a custom NSView subclass that I'm trying to get to print. I have a controller run the following code:

```
MyCustomView *printableView = [[MyCustomView alloc] init];
NSPrintOperation *po = [NSPrintOperation printOperationWithView:printableView];
[po runOperation];
```

When I set breakpoints, this code gets run, and the custom pagination methods (`knowsPageRange:` and `rectForPage:`) in the NSView get run, but the view's `drawRect:` method never gets called. It displays the print dialog, but all it prints are blank pages.

Why is my `drawRect:` method never getting called? Is there some sort of setup I have to do first?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The designated initializer for `NSView` is `-initWithFrame:`. While it's OK for `MyCustomView` to be initialized with `-init`, its implementation of `-init` ought to call `[super initWithFrame:someRect]`. Is it doing so?

Put another way, does your view have a frame rect?

Comment: Yes, its init does call `[super initWithFrame:someRect]`, but its frame is later modified in `rectForPage:` to fit the page size.

Comment: It seems strange to modify the view frame during `-rectForPage:`. Have you tried giving it some reasonable frame to start and not modifying it? Also, have you tried not implementing custom pagination, just to see what happens?

Comment: As it turns out, my custom subview had a property called "frameSize", which interfered with the existing function of the same name, causing it to get stuck at zero. Your answer helped me find the problem! Thanks!

Comment: I found that

rectForPage:
also required.